# Creating Command objects at run-time

Tags: c++, design-patterns, console

I'm trying to write a console for a game engine which will allow me to type in commands to perform tasks, such as change the map, spawn an enemy etc.

I've been trying to do this with the Command pattern (following the example from gameprogrammingpatterns.com).  See below for the outline of my current code structure.

`parseCommand` processes the `string` from the user, extracting the command name and arguments (currently using just whitespace separation).  The next step is where I'm stuck.  I need to create a `Command*` somehow to call `execute` on but I only have the `string` name of the command.

I could have a giant bunch of `if` statements in my `parseCommand` function, such as:

```
if (cmdName == "spawn")
   return new SpawnEnemyCommand();
```

Alternatively I could store a pointer to each command in my`Console` class, e.g. `Command *spawnNewEnemy = new SpawnNewEnemy();` and then in `parseCommand` do `if (cmdName == "spawn") spawnNewEnemy->execute();`.  This second option seems to be how the gameprogrammingpatterns book does it.

Neither of these options seems very practical if I end up with hundreds of console commands.  I've studied all the articles and posts I can find on this pattern but it isn't helping clarify the situation for me.

How can I cleanly instantiate the correct `Command` object from within `parseCommand`?

**Command interface base class:**

```
class Command {
public:
    virtual ~Command() { }
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};
```

**Example interface implementation:**

```
class SpawnEnemyCommand : public Command {
public:
    void execute() {
        // method calls to perform command go here
    }
};
```

**Console class header:**

```
class Console {
public:
    Command* parseCommand(std::string);
    bool validateCommand(std::string, std::vector<std::string>);
};
```

Comment: How about a [map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) that maps the command string to the command (like e.g. `std::unordered_map<std::string, Command*>`)? Split all arguments into a vector of strings that you pass to the commands `execute` function so it can handle arguments in an `argv`-like manner.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Thanks for the reply.  I did start work on using `std::map` but then I realised I would have to initialise every `Command*` in the map up front.  On a particular run of the program I may only use a couple of commands.

Comment: You can add elements to a map conditionally at run-time just like adding elements to a vector. And even if you add all possible command strings to the map, you can let the `Command*` in the data be null pointers, and only set those that matter on that particular run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By relying on a *dictionary* (e.g, [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) or [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map))  that maps a *command identifier* (i.e., a `std::string` object) to a `Command` object, you can design a factory with dynamic registry for your `Command` objects.

First, extend `Command` by including another virtual member function, `clone()`, that allows us to implement [The Prototype Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern):

```
class Command {
public:
   // ...
   virtual std::unique_ptr<Command> clone() const = 0;
};
```

The `clone()` virtual member function does what its name suggests: it *clones* the object. That is, `SpawnEnemyCommand` would override `Command::clone()` in the following way:

```
class SpawnEnemyCommand : public Command {
public:
   // ...
   std::unique_ptr<Command> clone() const override {
      // simply create a copy of itself
      return std::make_unique<SpawnEnemyCommand>(*this);
   }
};
```

This way, your command objects can be copied *polymorphically* through the `Command` interface – i.e., you don't need to know the concrete type of the command to be copied. All you need to do to copy a `Command` object is to call its `clone()` virtual member function. For example, the following function copies the `Command` passed as an argument regardless of the underlying concrete type:

```
std::unique_ptr<Command> CopyCommand(const Command& cmd) {
    return cmd.clone();
}
```

With this in mind, you are ready to design a factory for command objects, `CommandFactory`, that supports dynamically registering your command objects:

```
class CommandFactory {
public:
   void registerCommand(std::string id, std::unique_ptr<Command>);
   std::unique_ptr<Command> createCommand(std::string id) const;
private:
   std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Command>> registry_;
};
```

It all boils down to a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Command>>` data member. Indexing this data member by a command identifier, which is an `std::string`, we retrieve a `Command` object – This is the prototype object we will use for cloning.

The `registerCommand()` member function adds a `Command` prototype to the registry:

```
void CommandFactory::registerCommand(std::string cmdId, std::unique_ptr<Command> cmd) {
   registry_[cmdId] = std::move(cmd);
}
```

The `createCommand()` member function clones the `Command` prototype corresponding to the requested command identifier:

```
std::unique_ptr<Command> CommandFactory::createCommand(std::string cmdId) const {
   auto const it = registry_.find(cmdId);
   if (it == registry_.end())
      return nullptr; // no such a command in the registry

   auto const& cmdPtr = it->second;
   return cmdPtr->clone();
}
```

As an example program:

```
auto main() -> int {
   CommandFactory factory;
   factory.registerCommand("spawn", std::make_unique<SpawnEnemyCommand>());

   // ...

   auto cmdPtr = factory.createCommand("spawn");
   cmdPtr->execute();
}
```

You can also extend this factory to add support for dynamically *deregistering* your already-registered `Command` prototypes.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write up such a clear and detailed answer.

Comment: Wow, the details in the answer, amazing. Thank you 果歩プライ!